# gcm use crontab to execute php and call another php to send message

Tags: php, centos, cron, google-cloud-messaging

I use CentOS crontab to execute a get.php file to grab data. In this file, it will include another file to send gcm message if the data updated. The problem is that downloading data is successful, but send_message.php is not working. need help.

get.php

```
if(!mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $sql = "insert into data (data1, data2) values ('x','y')");";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('MySQL query error');
    echo 'Insert Success</br>';

    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    if(include($dir.'/send_message.php')!=1){
        die('send Message Fail.');
    }

}else{
    echo 'Already Download';
}
```

"send Message Fail" is not display. It means send_message.php should be include and execute.

send_message.php

> ```
> include_once './db_functions.php';
> include_once './GCM.php';
> $db = new DB_Functions();
> $gcm = new GCM();
> $registatoin_ids = $db->getAllUsers();
> $message = array('title' => 'data1',
>       'mes' => 'message1'
>         );
> $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
> ```

crontab

> 10,30 12,14,16 * * 7 /usr/bin/php -q
>   /var/www/html/jackwu/gasprice/get.php >>
>   /var/www/html/jackwu/gasprice/getcpc.log

If I use my browser and call send_message.php it will work, my device will receive message.
crontab can update data, but it cannot send message to me.

Can anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: U try `send_message.php` from your browser, but did you try running `get.php`? It might error, especially if that's your exact code since you have an extra `);"` there...

Comment: I try to use browser to open get.php, it is the same. data is update but not message.

Comment: I solve, I use curl to call send_message.php on my server instead of use include() or require(). Although this is not a best solution.... thanks for answer.

Comment: i have same problem, i use curl but it not work . i use include_once './GCM.php'  for this how to use curl will u help me.

Comment: I solve the problem. Just do not use curl. Use another functions to call .php file